# Adding digits entered in input boxes with keyup event in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am looking to display the addition of four values entered in the input boxes

```
<td><input type="text" value="22" style="width:60px;margin:6px;" ng-keyup="getkeys($event)" ng-model="one"></td>
<td><input type="text"  style="width:60px;margin:6px;" ng-keyup="getkeys($event)" ng-model="two"></td>
<td><input type="text"  style="width:60px;margin:6px;" ng-keyup="getkeys($event)" ng-model="three"></td>
<td><input type="text"  style="width:60px;margin:6px;" ng-keyup="getkeys($event)" ng-model="four"></td>
```

And this is my js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.getkeys = function (event) {


if($scope.one==='' || $scope.two==='' || $scope.three==='' || $scope.four==="" )
{
  $scope.one=parseInt("0");
  $scope.two=parseInt("0");
  $scope.three=parseInt("0")
  $scope.four=parseInt("0")
}

$scope.keyval = parseInt($scope.one)+parseInt($scope.two)+parseInt($scope.three)+parseInt($scope.four);


console.log($scope.keyval);
}
});
```

what i want is as soon as someone enters the value in the input boxes ,sum of all the four gets displayed ,the problem is if firstly user enters value in any box it display NaN ,until all the four values are entered any idea how to achieve it?
And how to know which ng-model value has been entered ,just like this.value in js

Comment: Use the [`ng-change` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange). It is better integrated with the [ngModel controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the other fields are empty & trying to parseInt & add an empty field value will result in `NaN`.Alternatively you can pass 0 if field is empty

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.getkeys = function(event) {
    if ($scope.one === '' || $scope.two === '' || $scope.three === '' || $scope.four === "") {
      $scope.one = parseInt("0");
      $scope.two = parseInt("0");
      $scope.three = parseInt("0")
      $scope.four = parseInt("0")
    }

    $scope.keyval = parseInt(($scope.one) || 0, 10) + parseInt($scope.two || 0, 10) + parseInt($scope.three || 0, 10) + parseInt($scope.four || 0, 10);


    console.log($scope.keyval);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" value="22" style="width:60px;margin:6px;" ng-keyup="getkeys($event)" ng-model="one">
    <input type="text" style="width:60px;margin:6px;" ng-keyup="getkeys($event)" ng-model="two">
    <input type="text" style="width:60px;margin:6px;" ng-keyup="getkeys($event)" ng-model="three">
    <input type="text" style="width:60px;margin:6px;" ng-keyup="getkeys($event)" ng-model="four"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- You don't need to bind a keyUp event, angularjs does that work for us.
- Initialize the model `one` within the controller.
- Create a function, i.e `getTotal()`
- Use the object `Number` to convert the entered values to numbers.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.getTotal = function() {
    return Number($scope.one) +
      Number($scope.two) +
      Number($scope.three) +
      Number($scope.four)
  };

  $scope.one = 22;
  $scope.two = 0;
  $scope.three = 0;
  $scope.four = 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" style="width:60px;margin:6px;" ng-model="one">
  <input type="text" style="width:60px;margin:6px;" ng-model="two">
  <input type="text" style="width:60px;margin:6px;" ng-model="three">
  <input type="text" style="width:60px;margin:6px;" ng-model="four">

  <p>Total</p>
  <span>{{getTotal()}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Minior modification on @Ele code.
Change the input type from text to number to facilitate the key up event and disable characters to be entered

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.getTotal = function() {
    return Number($scope.one) +
      Number($scope.two) +
      Number($scope.three) +
      Number($scope.four)
  };

  $scope.one = 22;
  $scope.two = 0;
  $scope.three = 0;
  $scope.four = 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="number" style="width:60px;margin:6px;" ng-model="one">
  <input type="number" style="width:60px;margin:6px;" ng-model="two">
  <input type="number" style="width:60px;margin:6px;" ng-model="three">
  <input type="number" style="width:60px;margin:6px;" ng-model="four">

  <p>Total</p>
  <span>{{getTotal()}}</span>
</div>
```